# Email/Username combination is incorrect error in login system

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a login system on my website where someone can create an account, then logout and then log back in. A message displays when a user tries to log into an account that doesn't exist. "Email/Username combination is incorrect". The problem I am having is that this message is displaying even when the account does exist.

Here is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

header("Location: home.php");

$_SESSION["success"] = "You are now logged in";

}


?>
<html>

<head>


</head>


<body>

<form action="verify_registration_form.php" method="post">
<br>
<input type="username" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" required>
<br><br><br><br><input type="password" id="user_pass_word" name="user_pass_word" placeholder="Password" required>
<br><br><br><br><input type="email" id="user_email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" required>
<br><br><br><br><input type="submit" class="submit_registration_form_button" id="submit_registration_form_button" name="submit_registration_form_button" value="Sign Up">

</form>

<form action="verify_login_form.php" method="post">

<input type="username" id="user_email_login" name="user_email_login" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="password" id="user_pass_word_login" name="user_pass_word_login" placeholder="Password" required>
<input type="submit" class="submit_user_login_form_button" id="submit_user_login_form_button" name="submit_registration_form_button" value="Log In">

</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Here is home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {


header('Location: index.php');

}



?>
<html>

<head>


</head>


<body>

<?php

echo $_SESSION["success"];


?>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>

<p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>


<br><br>

<form action="logout.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" id="logoutbutton" name="logoutbutton" class="logoutbutton" value="Logout">
</form>

<?php  endif ?>

</body>


</html>
```

Here is verify_login_form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

session_start();


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {

header("Location: index.php");

}else{

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "websiteusers");

if(!$connection) {

echo "Could not connect to MYSQL database";

}else{
echo "Sucessfully connected to MYSQL database";
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "websiteusers");
$useremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 
$_POST["user_email_login"]);
$userpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 
$_POST["user_pass_word_login"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE UserEmail='$useremail' AND UserPassWord='$hasheduserpassword'";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
header("Location: home.php");
}else{

echo "Email/Username combination is incorrect";

}



}

}




?>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>



</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare hashed passwords directly. You need to use [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. Change your code to something like:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "websiteusers");
$db->set_charset("utf8mb4");

$query = "SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE UserEmail=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["user_email_login"]);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
if($row && password_verify($_POST["user_pass_word_login"], $row['UserPassWord'])) {
```

The reason for this is that `password_hash()` is using a random salt to enhance the hash security, and the generated hash contains this salt. `password_verify()` extracts the salt from this hash, and hashes your compared string with the same salt, resulting (if the two passwords are the same) in the same hash, whereas using `password_hash()` a second time results in a different random salt used, which won't generate the same hash, and thus the compare will fail (thanks @Aurelien for this explanation).

Note that `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not intended for protecting from SQL injection, and if used for this purpose some day will fail you. You should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @Vack Guy the reason for this is that password_hash() is using a random salt to enhance the hash security, and the generated hash contains this salt. password_verify() extracts the salt from one hash, and hash your compared string with the same salt, resulting in the same hash, whereas using password_hash a second time (and comparing the 2 generated string yourself) results in a different random salt used, which won't generate the same hash.

Comment: @Aurelien that's a great explanation of the working, I've added it to the answer. Thanks,

Comment: I have changed                                 
 $hasheduserpassword = password_hash($userpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$query = "SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE UserEmail='$useremail' AND UserPassWord='$hasheduserpassword'";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

Comment: to                                                                                                        $query = "SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE UserEmail='$useremail'";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1 && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) && password_verify($userpassword, $row['UserPassWord'])) {                                                                                                
         and I am still getting Email/Username combination is incorrect even if the account exist

Comment: @VackGuy I suggest you break down the `if` condition and see what part of it is failing. e.g. `if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) or die (mysqli_error($connection)); if password_verify($userpassword, $row['UserPassWord'])) { ...` and put in `else` clauses to output appropriate error messages

Comment: O.K I changed                                                                                    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1 /* && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) && password_verify($userpassword, $row['UserPassWord']) */) {

Comment: to                                                                                                                           if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1 /* && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) && password_verify($userpassword, $row['UserPassWord']) */) {                                     
             and now whenever I submit the form on index.php I stay on index.php and It does not go to verify_login_form.php

Comment: @VackGuy you can't comment out that code, it's required to check for a valid username/password combination.

Comment: @VackGuy if this hasn't solved your problem, please don't mark the answer accepted. It will prevent others from coming up with solutions.